# Run spark job in parallel and using single spark context running in local mode

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I need to run some HQLs via spark. I have a jar having class that creates dataset from JSON, perform HQL and create JSON. Finally, save that JSON to a text file in local file system.

Spark is running on local mode.

**Problem**
: Jobs are sequential and every job is starting spark context. Hence, taking more time.

---

I want to create single Spark Context and execute jobs in parallel.

**Option 1 : Queque based model**

I can create a infinitely running job that starts spark context and listen on kafka queue. *JSON data & HQL* are passed as kafka message.

**Option 2 : Spark Streaming**

Use spark streaming with kafka to propagate *JSON data & HQL*

OR is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: you can also use multithreading (e.g. using parallel collections or creating threads manually) in your class to fire spark jobs simulanously using 1 Spark Context, see e.g. https://hadoopist.wordpress.com/2017/02/03/how-to-use-threads-in-spark-job-to-achieve-parallel-read-and-writes/

Comment: @RaphaelRoth I agree with multithread model. Along with this, in my case, small async jobs are coming to spark. I don't know data in advance. So, need to go with queue based approach I guess.